# How to call a Mathematica function inside Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interop, wolfram-mathematica

How to call a Mathematica function inside Matlab?  There are certain symbolic equation manipulation/simiplification that's particularly easy to do in Mathematica, at least to me, and I'd like to use Mathematica directly instead of having to burden myself to making it in Matlab.

Comment: Why not use Mathematica for everything?  Doesn't it do most of the numerical stuff you can do in Matlab?

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6044-mathematica-symbolic-toolbox-for-matlab-version-2-0

Comment: @japreiss  I have some built Matlab script and don't want to abandon them.  I think my question is a perfectly legitimate one and many people wonder about it.

Comment: @user1664196 wasn't trying to say the question is bad, just wondering.  I upvoted the question just now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some FEX options:

1. [SMATLINK - Let Matlab Dance with Mathematica](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20573)
2. [Mathematica Symbolic Toolbox for MATLAB--Version 2.0](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6044-mathematica-symbolic-toolbox-for-matlab-version-2-0) as also suggested by Dennis Jaherudin

Comment: Does this SMATLINK still exist? I could not find installation files.

Comment: did you try to "download zip" and then unzip in folder and play with the m files and the example?

Comment: I did, but inside the zip file I could not find any type of installation files...

Comment: there are no "installation files", just .m files and a compiled 32-bit mex file (you need matlab 32 bit). you open in matlab editor one of the m files and read the documentation on how to use it.

Comment: yes, sorry, I did not give it enough though. I am using a 64-bit machine. Is there any alternative other than installing a 32-bit matlab?